# Grouping items in a varchar column into age band using case

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to create age band from a varchar column with both numeric and categorical. the column contains age values

```
0-12
13
11
23
30
25
32
31
34
35
42
43
39
47
50
55
61
62
over 64
favorites
```

I tried this

```
 CASE
   WHEN Age='0-12' THEN '0-12'
   when Age BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN '15-30'
   when Age BETWEEN 31 AND 63 THEN '31-63'
   when Age= 'over 64' then 'over 64'
   when Age='favorites'then 'favorites'
 END AS 'Age group',
```

or below

```
 CASE
   when Age BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN '15-30'
   when Age BETWEEN 31 AND 63 THEN '31-63'
   when Age= 'over 64' then 'over 64'
   else Age
 END AS 'Age group'
```

I was expecting

```
0-12
15-30
31-63
over 64
favorites
```

I keep getting following error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '0-12' to data type int.

What am I doing wrong and whats the correct way to write this please? I am also happy to try this in python (if someone has a solution)
thanks in advance for the help

Comment: By comparing your column to an `INT` you force SQL server to convert every value in your column to an `INT` thereby causing the error.

Comment: I suggest changing your table design and storing the age as a pure integer column.  Then, write a query which generates the ranges/buckets you want.

Comment: This is a terrible database design, you should store a date of birth, not an age, and certainly not an age bracket, this is all stuff that can be computed if you store the date of birth, but causes you all sorts of issues when stored like this.

Comment: @DaleK I thought same when i saw the dataset, but its what i have to work with. how do i attempt the try_convert , please can you show with example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) because you are comparing `Age` to an `int` range, but not all your `Age` values can be implicitly converted to an `int`. `TRY_CONVERT` doesn't give an error when it is unable to convert a value.

You also don't need to explicitly test for the other values since you want to use them unchanged.

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
    WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int, Age) BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN '15-30'
    WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int, Age) BETWEEN 31 AND 63 THEN '31-63'
    ELSE Age
    END AS 'Age group'  
FROM Test;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cethbs32)

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** - code that returns a single,  scalar value. All different "paths" in your `CASE` should return the same datatype - if they don't (and in your case - they don't), then SQL Server will look at the various datatypes returned and will try to standardize on one datatype - based on defined and documented [datatype precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

In your case - most "paths" return string values - except the `ELSE` which returns an `INT` and according to the SQL Server type precedence rules, `INT` is preferred, so this `CASE` expression tries to convert all returned values to `INT` - which is why you get that error, since most of your strings can't be interpreted as `INT`....

Also, your condition `WHEN Age = 'over 64'` is odd - I'm assuming that `Age` is an `INT` column - so you **cannot** compare to a string, really ... you need to use `WHEN Age > 64 ...` - right?

So to fix this - you need to pay attention to **always** returning the **same datatype** from your `CASE` paths - thus you need to cast your `Age` column to a string value:

```
CASE
    WHEN Age BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN '15-30'
    WHEN Age BETWEEN 31 AND 63 THEN '31-63'
    WHEN Age > 64 THEN 'over 64'
    ELSE CAST(Age AS VARCHAR(10))    -- CAST to a VARCHAR value
END AS 'Age group',
```

Comment: I tried running it using you query, but i still get same error

Comment: @lili80: did you use **just this one `CASE` expression** in your `SELECT`  - or more columns/expressions? Quite possibly you still have other comparisons in your SQL that fail...

Comment: @marc_s, its the only case statement in the query

Comment: @DaleK not sure where to add the try_convert expression. Are you able to put it in the query for me please

Comment: @lili80 there is no case statement, as we keep saying it's a case expression

Comment: @marc_s age is not an int and contains non-int values - see the data in the question which I have reformatted. Which is the first issue, you have solved the second

Answer (score -1):

You have string data that cannot be converted to number..
assuming you need the original data, try this

```
create table #tmp_agelookup (
age_string varchar(20), 
age_number int 
)
insert into #tmp_agelookup(age_string)
select distinct age from (yourtable)

update #tmp_agelookup set age_number = 
case when age_string = '0-12' then 12 
when agestring = 'over 64' then 64 else age_string end
```

now you can join this table and use your case statement over the age_number column.
hope this helps.

Comment: Case is an *expression* not a *statement*

Comment: I can't follow how that query helps.can you create a dbfiddle which shows it working please

Comment: am confused with the above query

Comment: it creates a temp table where you have a mapped column to actual data (age_string )and another column(age_int) to convert values to int so that you can use this in the original query using a join like a lookup..  since you cannot convert "over 64" to int , you need to specify 64 and then group as age_int >63 for 64+

Comment: I'm sure that's useful fo something, but it's not what OP is asking for

Comment: @DaleK  [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tsHhuAe1oDzibH8L1DFAzJ/0)

Comment: Yip, those results are not what the OP is asking for. Every age between 15-63 should be grouped into 2 bands, 15-30 & 31-63. Your code is not doing that.